# Drawing a diamond of numbers in a 2d array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've been solving some coding questions to get myself prepared for a coding interview, and found out a question that seemed kind of puzzling. I solved the question after spending some time on it; however, the code looks hardcoded and has no style. So, I was wondering if I could get some feedbacks on styling the code, or perhaps getting an better idea of approaching the problem.

The question basically asks you to draw a diamond of numbers with a pattern in 2d array.
It gives a coordinate of 'x' and range of x. From the x, the numbers spread one by one until the range. So, there are 4 different inputs, N (the size of an array), X, Y (the coordinate of 'x' as (rows, cols)), and R (range).

If they were given a size of 8, coordinate of (4,5) with a range of 3, the result would be like,

```
0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 3 2 3 0 0
0 0 3 2 1 2 3 0
0 3 2 1 x 1 2 3
0 0 3 2 1 2 3 0
0 0 0 3 2 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And the below is what I have,

```
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    char[][] arr = new char[n][n];
    int r = sc.nextInt() - 1;
    int c = sc.nextInt() - 1;
    int range = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }

    arr[r][c] = 'x';


    int num = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        //Cross
        if (c-num > -1) {
            arr[r][c - num] = (char) (num + '0');
        }
        if (c+num < n) {
            arr[r][c + num] = (char) (num + '0');
        }
        if (r-num > -1) {
            arr[r - num][c] = (char) (num + '0');
        }
        if (r+num < n) {
            arr[r + num][c] = (char) (num + '0');
        }
        //Diagonal
        if (i > 0) {
            int sum = num - 1, delta = 1;

            while (sum != 0) {
                if (r-sum > -1 && c+delta < n) {
                    arr[r - sum][c + delta] = (char) (num + '0');
                }
                sum--;
                delta++;
            }
            sum = num - 1; delta = 1;
            while (sum != 0) {
                if (r+sum < n && c-delta > -1) {
                    arr[r + sum][c - delta] = (char) (num + '0');
                }
                sum--;
                delta++;
            }
            sum = num - 1; delta = 1;
            while (sum != 0) {
                if (r-sum > -1 && c-delta > -1) {
                    arr[r - sum][c - delta] = (char) (num + '0');
                }
                sum--;
                delta++;
            }
            sum = num - 1; delta = 1;
            while (sum != 0) {
                if (r+sum < n && c+delta > -1) {
                    arr[r + sum][c + delta] = (char) (num + '0');
                }
                sum--;
                delta++;
            }
        }
        num++;
    }
```

I could not figure out any other way to take care of the diagonal numbers other than using four different while-loops. I would appreciate any kind of feedback. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like X and Y are swapped.

Comment: oops, I meant to write (rows, cols). I'll edit the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Note if your code is already working, and you just want some feedback for improvement, then your question might be better suited to our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over the array once, and set the values based on the relative distance of the current location `(i, j)` to the fixed coordinate `(x, j)`.

Your code could look like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variables
        int n = 8;
        int x = 4 - 1; // coordinates are one-based
        int y = 5 - 1; // coordinates are one-based
        int r = 3;
        char[][] array = new char[n][n];

        // logic
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int dist = Math.abs(x - i) + Math.abs(y - j); // calculate distance

                if(dist == 0) {         // at x,y
                    array[i][j] = 'x';
                } else if (dist <= r) { // distance to x,y is within range
                    array[i][j] = (char) (dist + '0');
                } else {                // distance to x,y is outside of range
                    array[i][j] = '0';
                }
            }
        }

        // dump output
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array)
                           .replace("], ", "]\n")
                           .replace("[", "")
                           .replace("]", "")
                           .replace(", ", " "));
    }
}
```

Which yields the following output:

```
0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 3 2 3 0 0
0 0 3 2 1 2 3 0
0 3 2 1 x 1 2 3
0 0 3 2 1 2 3 0
0 0 0 3 2 3 0 0
0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you want to be even more concise, you can replace the branched `if… else if… else` statement with ternary operators:

```
array[i][j] = dist == 0 ? 'x' : dist <= r ? (char) (dist + '0') : '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly compact method. On each iteration `i` we fill a single-character wide `i+1` by `i+1` diamond-shaped ring, centered on `(row, col)`, with value `i`. To avoid filling the interior of the diamond we check that the manhattan distance to `(row, col)` is equal to `i` - this is only true for cells on the boundary of the diamond.

```
static char[][] buildDiamond(int n, int row, int col, int range)
{
  char[][] arr = new char[n][n];
  for(char[] a : arr) Arrays.fill(a, '0');
  arr[row][col] = 'x';

  for(int i=1; i<=range; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
      for(int k=0; k<=i; k++)
        if(Math.abs(k-j) + Math.abs(k+j-i) == i)
          arr[row+k-j][col+k+j-i] += i;

  return arr;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  for(char[] a : buildDiamond(7, 3, 3, 3)) 
    System.out.println(new String(a).replaceAll(".", "$0 "));
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 3 0 0 0 
0 0 3 2 3 0 0 
0 3 2 1 2 3 0 
3 2 1 x 1 2 3 
0 3 2 1 2 3 0 
0 0 3 2 3 0 0 
0 0 0 3 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using floodfill, although depending on your level it might be a bit far.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

EDIT: Robby Cornelissen's code looks much cleaner and simpler than mine so you should probably check out his. However, floodfill is a pretty important concept for later on so might as well check it out.

The article is pretty long, but the GIF in the article is the most important part.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Get inputs (I used BufferedReader, Scanner works fine as well)
        //My inputs are formatted as 'N X Y R' (ex. '8 4 5 3')
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");
        int N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        int R = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1;
        int C = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1;
        int range = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        char[][] arr = new char[N][N];

        //Make everything in array '0'
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(arr[i], '0');
        }

        //Floodfill using BFS
        //FYI: this BFS is iterative, not recursive
        Queue<int[]> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(new int[]{0, R, C});
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            int[] current = q.remove();
            if (arr[current[1]][current[2]] == '0' && current[0] <= range) {
                arr[current[1]][current[2]] = (current[0]+"").charAt(0);
                if(current[1]+1 < N) q.add(new int[]{current[0]+1, current[1]+1, current[2]});
                if(current[1]-1>= 0) q.add(new int[]{current[0]+1, current[1]-1, current[2]});
                if(current[2]+1 < N) q.add(new int[]{current[0]+1, current[1], current[2]+1});
                if(current[2]-1>= 0) q.add(new int[]{current[0]+1, current[1], current[2]-1});
            }
        }
        arr[R][C] = 'x';

        //Print out the final grid
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j< N; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```